# How does changing metadata in JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript

In the console, I get `abc` despite setting `{writable:false}`. Could you explain how changing metadata works?

```js
let portfolio = {
  myFirstName: "Bob",
  myLastName: "Alice",
  myAge: 26,
  aboutMe: function() {
    return ("First Name: " + this.myFirstName + "; Last Name: " + this.myLastName + "; Age: " + this.myAge + ";");
  }
};
Object.defineProperty(portfolio, "myFirstName", { writable: false });
Object.defineProperty(portfolio, "myFirstName", { value: "abc" });
console.log(portfolio.myFirstName);
```

Comment: Why all of this instead of just a `class` with getters and setters?

Comment: If you do this: `portfolio.myFirstName = 'abc'`, myFirstName will remain Bob

Comment: I'd guess that `Object.defineProperty` doesn't honour the writable flag. I'd have to check the specs to be sure how this should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`writable: false` only has an effect on `Object.defineProperty` if `configurable` is also set to `false`. See step 7 of the [`ValidateAndApplyPropertyDescriptor` algorithm](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-validateandapplypropertydescriptor):

```
Else if IsDataDescriptor(current) and IsDataDescriptor(Desc) are both true, then
  If current.[[Configurable]] is false and current.[[Writable]] is false, then
    If Desc.[[Writable]] is present and Desc.[[Writable]] is true, return false.
    If Desc.[[Value]] is present and SameValue(Desc.[[Value]], current.[[Value]]) is false, return false.
    Return true.
```

That's likely because as long as a property is configurable, nothing stops you from changing the value of `writable` back to `true`, e.g.

```
Object.defineProperty(
  portfolio,
  "myFirstName",
  {value: "abc", writable: true}
);
```

Note that any property declared as part of an object literal automatically has `{writable: true, configurable: true, enumerable: true}`.

#### Examples

Can't assign because `writable` and `configurable` are both `false`:

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'test', {
  value: 42,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
});
console.log(obj);
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'test', {value: 21});
console.log(obj);
```

Can assign a value because `writable` or `configurable` are `true`:

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'test', {
  value: 42,
  configurable: true,
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true
});
console.log(obj);
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'test', {value: 21});
console.log(obj);


var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'test', {
  value: 42,
  configurable: false,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true
});
console.log(obj);
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'test', {value: 21});
console.log(obj);
```

Lastly, if `writable` and `configurable` are both `false` but if the new value is the same as the current value, no error will be thrown since no change is actually being made to the property:

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'test', {
  value: 42,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
});
console.log(obj);
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'test', {value: 42});
console.log(obj);
```

---

Setting `writable: false` will work as expected for normal assignments (`foo.bar = 42`) because such assignments go through [`OrdinarySetWithOwnDescriptor`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-ordinarysetwithowndescriptor) which check the `writable` value of an existing property descriptor first.

Comment: That's interesting. That's basically an Object.freeze() then on a single property. Interesting.

Answer (score 8):

in your 2nd line `Object.defineProperty(portfolio, "myFirstName", { value: "abc" });` you are defining the property again.

You are not assigning a value. You are tossing out the old property and replacing it with a brand spanking new one. *(Technically incorrect, it goes through a lot of steps to [evaluate and apply values to property properties](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-validateandapplypropertydescriptor), but for simple understanding, I believe this suffices as understanding, as it feels like a new one in this scenario. Please read the link if you wish to have the complex truth)*

To assign a new value use `portfolio.myFirstName = "value here"` and you see it's write protected.

```js
let portfolio = {
  myFirstName: "Bob",
  myLastName: "Alice",
  myAge: 26,
  aboutMe: function() {
    return ("First Name: " + this.myFirstName + "; Last Name: " + this.myLastName + "; Age: " + this.myAge + ";");
  }
};
Object.defineProperty(portfolio, "myFirstName", { writable: false });
portfolio.myFirstName = "Alice";
console.log(portfolio.myFirstName);
```

to prevent the workaround, call `Object.freeze()` on the object after modifying its property. This will also have other side effects like not being able to edit the values of other properties.

```js
let portfolio = {
  myFirstName: "Bob",
  myLastName: "Alice",
  myAge: 26,
  aboutMe: function() {
    return ("First Name: " + this.myFirstName + "; Last Name: " + this.myLastName + "; Age: " + this.myAge + ";");
  }
};
Object.defineProperty(portfolio, "myFirstName", { writable: false });
Object.freeze(portfolio);
Object.defineProperty(portfolio, "myFirstName", {value:"abc"});
console.log(portfolio.myFirstName);
```

Comment: If you add `portfolio.myAge = 27` before `Object.defineProperty(portfolio, "myFirstName", { writable: false });` then print it at the end it'll show it's a new object

Comment: *"You are not assigning a value. You are tossing out the old property and replacing it with a brand spanking new one."* That's not correct. The existing property descriptor is merged with the existing one. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-validateandapplypropertydescriptor

Comment: @FelixKling You are correct, I added in a little disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

You're working around that access restriction to hard-set the property. That only impacts the `portfolio.myFirstName` mutator.

You really can't block access to `defineProperty` like that. It's too low-level. That's probably a good thing, though, since it is dependable.